# Spring Autowiring issue - "required a bean that could not be found"

Tags: spring, eclipse, inversion-of-control, autowired

I am new to spring and am attempting to use autowire an instance of a crudrepository (from spring data) into another class (for testing purposes only, I will autowire this into my service layer after).  However, spring cannot find an instance of the bean to autowire.

Here is the **error message**:

```
Field repository in com.connor.ConnorApplication required a bean of type 'com.connor.dao.UserRepository' that could not be found.

Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.connor.dao.UserRepository' in your     configuration.
```

Here is **my code** for the class that runs my spring application:

```
package com.connor;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
//import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
//import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
//import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

import com.connor.dao.UserRepository;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ConnorApplication /*begin addition*/implements CommandLineRunner /*end addition*/{

//begin addition code
@Autowired 
private UserRepository repository;

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception
{
   System.out.println("-------------------------------------");      
   long numEntries = repository.count();
   System.out.println("There are " + numEntries + " entries in the user table");
   System.out.println("-------------------------------------");       
}

//end addition code

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ConnorApplication.class, args);
}
```

}

**Code for the crudrepository**

```
package com.connor.dao;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.connor.model.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer>{

}
```

Finally, here is a picture of my **folder structure**:

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xHjR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the spring-data project you are using (look for a dependency in pom.xml like `spring-boot-start-data-*` ) but probably you need to enable your repositories.

In spring-data-mongodb for example you would need `@EnableMongoRepositories` annotation or the equivalent configuration in application.properties or spring.xml.